# Codeigniter 2.1.3 with VQMOD possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter, vqmod

I have a purchased product called Multiscraper (MS), which is basically built on CI 2.1.3, and is a webpage scraper for various shopping carts.

**So, why do I want to use vqmod (of something else that can bring about similar results)?**
Because I have modifications and additions I want to make to improve the functionality of MS.

**Why do I not make these changes in the same file?**
Because the developers of the product post updates to their product which may offer improvements. If I start modifying the original files directly, it will become very difficult to manage these updates when they arrive.
I am hoping for a way to modify these files with only the functions I want to improve upon.
If it can be done with VQMOD, then it will be much easier to debug and fix things after an update.

**So I tried installing VQMOD and the effects only affect the \system\core and nothing else.**

How to manage it? Anybody?

NOTE: [I am aware that CI has functionality to extend classes. I posted another question on that subject here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809701/how-to-extend-classes-in-purchased-product-multiscraper-built-on-codeigniter-2): [How to extend classes in purchased product (Multiscraper) built on Codeigniter 2.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809701/how-to-extend-classes-in-purchased-product-multiscraper-built-on-codeigniter-2)

Answer (score 0):

No there's no version of this for codeigniter but you have an integration guide here
https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Integration-with-Other-Platforms